# Texture doesn't get updated after applying a compute shader

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader, gpgpu

I'm trying to apply a compute shader to a texture to update its values. I know it's not a very good question to just state something doesn't work, but I did spend a lot of hours trying to get this work.

The shader program compiles well. Changing the `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);` line to `glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS); glFinish();` doesn't make a difference.

Below is a minimal program to show the issue. SDL is merely for creating an invisible window for the GL context. The program is expected fill the texture with `0.5`s and print them, but only `0`s are printed..

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT WIDTH

static const char *SHADER =
  "#version 430\n" // "#version 310 es\n"

  "layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;\n"
  "layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform image2D image;\n"

  "void main() {\n"
    "imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(0.5f));\n"
  "}\n";

int main() {
  SDL_SetMainReady();
  assert(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO));
  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  assert(window);
  SDL_GLContext gl = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
  assert(gl);
  assert(glewInit() == GLEW_OK);

  GLuint tex;
  glGenTextures(1, &tex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_FLOAT, 0);
  glBindImageTexture(0, tex, 0, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);

  GLuint shader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(shader, 1, &SHADER, 0);
  glCompileShader(shader);
  GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(program, shader);
  glLinkProgram(program);
  glUseProgram(program);
  glDispatchCompute(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1);
  glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
  glFinish();
  static float a[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4];
  glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, a);

  puts((const char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) printf("%f\n", a[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not generate mipmaps (with  [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)), you have to change the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`. Since the default filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, the texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete" if you do not change the minimize function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
       
glBindImageTexture(0, tex, 0, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```